# Views: How to list nodes by 2 vocabularies with “%” on url path for contextual filters

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type with 2 different Term references. I wanna use Views to list “Term one” with “%” on url path, and **use “Term two” as section**. See below for details.

**Vocabulary term one:**
Book type A
Book type B
Book type C

**Vocabulary term two:**
Book style A
Book style B
Book style C

### List result: on Book type A


Book style A
    - node 101 title, author name
    - node 102 title, author name
    - node 103 title, author name

Book style B
    - node 111 title, author name
    - node 112 title, author name
    - node 113 title, author name

Book style C
    - node 121 title, author name
    - node 122 title, author name
    - node 123 title, author name

---

**— — updated info @ Sep. 9th 2014 @ 1:16pm**

I created a content View, which has “Content: Type Book A” and set the path as “/booka/%. It came out fine except I don’t know how to use the 2nd Term as section to list all those node under their style.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what about it worked, and what didn't?  In general, people here aren't in the business of doing all the work for you.

Comment: @Geoff Sorry, I just updated my question. Everything goes well on my View except the 2nd Term. I dont know how to list these nodes under their style.

Comment: how about using a table with fields, include the style (exclude from display), and then 'group' the fields by the style (under table settings).  It's not terribly pretty, but some simple css can easily improve the layout.

Comment: @geoff Yes, grouping is the way to go, and OP can always tinker with the view template files in addition to CSS.

Comment: @Geoff That work perfect. Can you Answer that on "Answer Your Question"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

- create the view as a table with fields
- include the style field (exclude from display)
- under table settings, 'group' the results by the style field

You can tweak the layout for the headers with some simple css